# Pipe an observable to update list of items with result from api

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have an *observable* which pumps a list of items. I need to *pipe* the observable so that each of the items would do an api call, update itself with the result from the api call and finally provide an updated list of items from the observable.

- Consider an array like below
  `[{id: 1, name: 'a'}, {id: 2, name: 'b'}, {id: 3, name: 'c'}]`
- Each item needs to do an api call which returns if its a 'new' or 'old' item
  GET `/api/type/:id` returns `new` / `old`
- Update the item to take the api result value on a new `type` property
- Return the updated list
  `[{id: 1, name: 'a', type: 'new'}, {id: 2, name: 'b', type: 'old'}, {id: 3, name: 'c', type: 'new'}]`

What kind of `rxjs` operators can i use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ok with doing this sequentially you could try something like this

```js
const items$ = from([{id: 1, name: 'a'}, {id: 2, name: 'b'}, {id: 3, name: 'c'}])

const request = async (data) => {
  // data here would be any single object in your array
  // and `doHttpRequest` is any function that returns the type
  // given the original object
  const type = await doHttpRequest(data)
  return {
    ...data,
    type
  }
}

const results$ = items$.pipe(
  // flatMap being used here since we're not returning
  // a synchronous value from request
  flatMap(request),
  toArray()
);

// somewhere else in your code
results$.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

If you omit the `toArray` part you could keep your observable as a stream of objects instead of a single array completing at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the lead. But the item$ observable pumps the whole array itself. So item$ would need to be `of([...items])`

Comment: You should be able to switch the observable from an observable of a single array to an observable of multiple objects by adding `flatMap(from)` to the beginning of that pipe, or you can change your request function to loop over an array of objects instead, whichever suits your needs better.

Answer (score 0):

You can send your data down by piping it in the httpRequest.

```
const item$ = from([{id: 1, name: 'a'}, {id: 2, name: 'b'}, {id: 3, name: 'c'}]);
    
item$.pipe(
  mergeMap(data => doHttpRequest(data).pipe(
    map(res=>({res:res, item:data}))
  )),
  mergeMap(({res, item})=>({...item, type:res})),
  toArray()
).subscribe( value => console.log(value))
```

In the second mergeMap you will get an object that has 2 keys: res & item. You can use it to add a new key into your object.

Answer (score 0):

Map your array to an array of observables and the use forkJoin to process them concurrently.

```js
const { forkJoin, map, of } = rxjs;

const items = [{id: 1, name: 'a'}, {id: 2, name: 'b'}, {id: 3, name: 'c'}];

observables = items.map(item =>
  httpRequest(item).pipe(
    map(type => ({ ...item, type }))
  )
);

forkJoin(observables).subscribe(results => {
  console.log(results);
});

function httpRequest (req) {
  return of(Math.random() > .5 ? 'new' : 'old');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.0/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha512-v0/YVjBcbjLN6scjmmJN+h86koeB7JhY4/2YeyA5l+rTdtKLv0VbDBNJ32rxJpsaW1QGMd1Z16lsLOSGI38Rbg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```